What kind of data can i retrieve with the Youtube-API?
I am trying to create a web app that is based on checking users' interactions with the profiles of their favorite creators, influncers and brands. I'm trying to figure out the feasibility of the idea and for that I would like to know if through the Youtube-API I can get this the kind of data I would like from a user who authenticates in my platform:
To know if he/she is subscribed to a specific channel, to know if he/she has liked a specific video or commented or shared the video and finally if the user has watched the video for at least X%.
Thanks in advance.
I'm not technical enough to understand the documentation, but i would like to know in order to know if i can start to build my idea.

there are non-official apis to fetch all this information with ease - see this: https://youtu.be/4fUEoHbCW04
